ARCH-LM test statistic in R package aTSA
I would like to perform an ARCH-LM test. At first, I calculated the LM statistic myself, by regressing the squared residuals on a constant and p lagged values. According to Engle (1982) the LM statistic is TR^2 with T observations and R^2 as determination coefficient of the auxillary regression.
Then, I tried the arch.test() function in aTSA, which returned completely different values with a totally reverse behavior. The larger the order, the smaller the statistic. Moreover the statistic does not appear to be chi-squared distributed given the combinations of order=degrees of freedom, statistic and p-value. Here are my steps:
#Accessing data

library(yfR)
CVX_data=yf_get(
  tickers = "CVX",
  first_date = "2020-01-02",
  last_date = "2021-12-31")

#Calculating data

attach(CVX_data)
close_ln=c(log(price_adjusted))
close_ln_d=c(NA, diff(log(price_adjusted)*100))

#New format

new_df=data.frame(ref_date, price_adjusted, close_ln, close_ln_d)
new_df_2=new_df[-c(1),]
comp_data=new_df_2[,4]

#Built-in ARCH test

ARM=arima(comp_data, order=c(2,0,0))
library(aTSA)
arch.test(ARM)

#ARCH test "by hand"

AR=ar(comp_data, aic=FALSE, order.max=2)

uhat2=(AR$resid)^2
obs=length(uhat2)

ch1 <- function(p){
    uhat2[-c(obs:(obs-p+1))]
}
ch2 <- function(p){
    c(seq(1:p), ch1(p))
}
ch3 <- function(p){
    replace(ch2(p), ch2(p)[1:p], NA)
}
ch4 <- function(p){
    c(1:p)
}
U <- function(p){
    sapply(ch4(p), ch3)
}
reg2 <- function(p){
    lm(uhat2 ~ U(p))
}
T <- function(p){
    503-2-p
}
R2 <- function(p){
    summary(reg2(p))$r.squared
}
Statistic <- function(p){
    T(p)*R2(p)  
}
Statistic(2)

Can someone explain this discrepancy?

Your code does not show the manual calculation of the ARCH-LM test. You may want to include that so that we can see exactly what you are doing.

I cannot digest this level of nesting, so I will not be able to answer the question, but hopefully someone else will be.
